# Multiple linear regression - how to handle variables that only apply to part of the dataset

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, missing-data

I often run into scenarios where certain independent variables only apply to part of the data. This is different from missing data, as I know that the variable does not apply to begin with. Here is an example:

```
y - continuous dependent variable
x1 - categorical/factor variable (levels a and b)
x2 - continuous variable - applies only to data points where x1 = a
x3 - continuous variable - applies only to data points where x1 = b
x4, x5 - continuous variables - apply to all data points
```

I want to build a multiple linear regression model using the above data set. Am I better off building two separate models by breaking my data set into A and B. Are there methods I could use to build a single model for all of my data.

Comment: "Doesn't apply" means "doesn't add or subtract anything from the prediction."  Sounds like a zero, doesn't it?

Comment: @whuber but then there could be zeroes where it does apply as well. If I substitute zero for NA, am I not diluting the effect of that variable?

Comment: Have you considered testing a decision tree regression instead? I've seen randomForest perform fairly well on these types of problems.

Comment: Remember, "NA" is wrong if it's meant in the sense of "not known".  You're *not* substituting zero for it.  You are placing zeros in such a way as to reflect how the model is supposed to behave.  You are not diluting the effect of anything, nor are you creating any synthetic information.  Models like this, and questions just like this one, have been described in various threads here. See questions about [modeling changepoints](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=changepoint+regression), for instance, where one slope applies for some subjects and another slope applies for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Let's examine the possibilities.**

The model you want will be something like

$$E[Y] = \alpha_{1;a} + \alpha_2 x_2 + \color{Gray}{0 x_3} + \alpha_4 x_4 + \alpha_5 x_5\tag{1}$$

for observations where $x_1=a$ and

$$E[Y] = \gamma_{1;b} + \color{Gray}{0 x_2} + \gamma_3 x_3 + \alpha_4 x_4 + \alpha_5 x_5\tag{2}$$

for observations where $x_1=b$.  In these models all the alphas and gammas are parameters to be estimated: there are five in each model--but the last two must be the same.  I didn't need to write terms like "$0 x_3$" and "$0 x_2$", but have included them to emphasize the similar structures of these models.

Normally we "dummy code" the categorical variable and (re-using the symbol "$x_1$") will set $x_1=0$ for category $a$ and $x_1=1$ for category $b$.

**Contemplate the following model:**

$$E[Y] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_{12} (1-x_1)x_2 + \beta_{13} x_1x_3 + \beta_4 x_4 + \beta_5 x_5.\tag{3}$$

It simplifies a little depending on the value of $x_1$.  For observations of type $a$, $x_1=0$ and so all terms with $x_1$ drop out entirely and $1-x_1=1$ simplifies some products:

$$E[Y] = \beta_0 +  \beta_{12} x_2 + \beta_4 x_4 + \beta_5 x_5.$$

For observations of type $b$, $x_1=1$ and so all terms with $1-x_1=0$ disappear, leaving

$$E[Y] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_{13} x_3 + \beta_4 x_4 + \beta_5 x_5.$$

Comparing these with $(1)$ and $(2)$ term by term helps us identify these new coefficients.  For instance, comparing constant terms gives

$$\beta_0=\alpha_{1;a};\ \beta_0+\beta_1=\gamma_{1;b}.$$

Comparing the coefficients of $x_2$ gives

$$\beta_{12} = \alpha_2;\ \beta_{13} = \gamma_3.$$

Similarly, $\beta_4$ plays the role of $\alpha_4$ for type-$a$ observations and $\gamma_4$ for type-$b$ observations, *etc.*  Evidently, model $(3)$ combines models $(1)$ and $(2)$, producing whichever one is suitable for the type of the observation.  It simultaneously enforces that the coefficients of $x_4$ and $x_5$ will be the same for either type of observation.

Here is an illustration of the fit of model $(3)$ (colored lines) to data generated according to models $(1)$ and $(2)$ (black dashed lines).  In order to do this, variables $x_4$ and $x_5$ were excluded from the model (so that they would not affect the results).

[image: Figure]

Evidently the fits work.

---

For those who would like to experiment further, here is the `R` code to generate such data according to models $(1)$ and $(2)$, fit all three models (the first two are separately fit to the corresponding subsets of the data, but the third is fit to *all* data), and study their results.

```R
n <- 99            # Amount of data
alpha <- c(-5, 10, 0, 2, -1)
gamma <- c(5, 0, 1)
sigma <- 5         # Error standard deviation
#
# Create data according to two models.
#
library(data.table)
X <- data.table(type = sample(c("a", "b"), n, replace=TRUE),
                x.2 = rnorm(n, 4),
                x.3 = rnorm(n, 7),
                x.4 = rnorm(n, 25),
                x.5 = rnorm(n, 35))
X[, x.1 := ifelse(type=="a", 0, 1)] # Dummy coding
X[type=="a", y.true := alpha[1] + alpha[2]*x.2 + alpha[4]*x.4 + alpha[5]*x.5]
X[type=="b", y.true := gamma[1] + gamma[3]*x.3 + alpha[4]*x.4 + alpha[5]*x.5]
X[, y := y.true + rnorm(n, sd=sigma)] # Add in some error.
#
# Fit the three fits.
#
fit.1 <- lm(y ~ x.2 + x.4 + x.5, data=X[type=="a"])
fit.2 <- lm(y ~ x.3 + x.4 + x.5, data=X[type=="b"])
fit.3 <- lm(y ~ x.1 + I((1-x.1)*x.2) + I(x.1*x.3) + x.4 + x.5, data=X)
#
# Study the parameter estimates.
#
for (fit in list(fit.1, fit.2, fit.3)) print(summary(fit))
#
# To illustrate graphically, redo without x.4 and x.5.
#
set.seed(17)
X[type=="a", y.true := alpha[1] + alpha[2]*x.2]
X[type=="b", y.true := gamma[1] + gamma[3]*x.3]
X[, y := y.true + rnorm(n, sd=sigma)] # Add in some error.
pairs(X[, .(x.1, x.2, x.3, y)])
fit.3 <- lm(y ~ x.1 + I((1-x.1)*x.2) + I(x.1*x.3) , data=X)

beta <- coef(fit.3)
colors <- c(a="DeepSkyBlue", b="Orange")
with(X, {
  plot(range(c(x.2, x.3)), range(y), type="n",
       xlab="x.2 or x.3", ylab="y")
  points(x.2[type=="a"], y[type=="a"], pch=19, col=colors["a"])
  points(x.3[type=="b"], y[type=="b"], pch=18, col=colors["b"])
  abline(alpha[1:2], lwd=2, lty=2)
  abline(gamma[c(1,3)], lwd=2, lty=2)
  abline(c(beta["(Intercept)"], beta["I((1 - x.1) * x.2)"]), 
         lwd=2, col=colors[1])
  abline(c(beta["(Intercept)"] + beta["x.1"], beta["I(x.1 * x.3)"]), 
         lwd=2, col=colors[2])
})
```